# How to create a virtual page for a feedback survey

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a custom plugin. One of the functions of this plugin is to send an email to a user requesting feedback on how well our staff was able to resolve the user's issue.

I'm not sure how this is done, but I envision being able to send an email to users with a link:

```
<a href="https://example.com/feedback-survey/?id=... ">Take the Survey<a>
```

Can somebody give me some hints (code would be great) that would show me how to register a page/slug in my plugin that would be generated dynamically from within my plugin when accessed?

I prefer to not authenticate. The URI is a one-time shot. Once the feedback form is submitted `feedback-survey/?id=` would no longer be accessible. It would generate a "You have already taken this survey."

The exact logic of what this virtual page will do probably isn't so important. I can handle the logic at that point. Specifically, I just want to know how to register a slug/URI, and trigger a function within my plugin to render the page/form when that URI is accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom post type for survey.

```
register_post_type( 'survey', // POST TYPE NAME
        array(
                'thumbnail',
                'labels' => array(
                        'name' => __( 'Surveys' ),
                        'singular_name' => __( 'survey' )
                ),
                'can_export'          => TRUE,
                'exclude_from_search' => FALSE,
                'publicly_surveyable'  => TRUE,
                'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-format-chat',
                'survey_var'           => 'survey',
                'show_ui'             => TRUE,
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
                'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes', 'excerpt' ),
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'show_in_menu'        => TRUE,
                'show_in_nav_menus'   => TRUE,
                'taxonomies' => array('person_type')
        )
);
```

Then when survey post creating. **$thash** is a random post name its are better than show ID. and link to this will be *yourpage.net/survey/$thash*

```
function insertSurvey($title, $content) {
    $t = time();
    $thash = md5($t);

    $my_query = array(
        'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $title ),
        'post_content'  => $content,
        'post_type' => 'survey',
        'post_name' => $thash,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1
    );
    $data = wp_insert_post( $my_query );
}
```

Then email

```
function contact_form_init() {
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
    $tel = strip_tags($_POST['tel']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $text = strip_tags($_POST['message']);


        $subject = 'Subject';

        $headers = "From: wordpress@yoursite.com \r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: replay@ryoursite.com \r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

        $message = '<html><body>';
        $message .= '<h1>Title/h1>';
        $message .= '<p><strong>Name</strong>: '.$name.'</p>';
        $message .= '<p><strong>Phone</strong>: '.$tel.'</p>';
        $message .= '<p><strong>Email</strong>: '.$email.'</p>';
        $message .= '<p><strong>Message</strong>: '.$text.'</p>';
        $message .= '<p>Send on: '.date("F j, Y, g:i a").'</p>';
        $message .= '</body></html>';

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


    exit;
}
```

Comment: Very much appreciated. So the key I was missing is that there needs to be a custom post type registered to create the slug. This is a lot of help for me. The survey results are needed to be saved as metadata for an already existing post type, but I think I can handle that. Would I be on the right track to say that just /survey/ could be the endpoint URI and thash could be in the querystring? Also, where do I create the /survey/ page html content (the form)? The results of the survey will be super simple data that needs to be saved as metadata to an existing custom post type.

Comment: Yes thash will be your post slug, for specific post. About form creation? should form be different for each survey? to each specific survey you allow complete only once, or you want multiple allow multiple visitors to complete same survey page?

Comment: Multiple visitors fill the same page, but it is in reference to their own $post_id. With your help above and some more research, I was able to get a working solution. Thanks for your help!